# VideoPlayerでストリーミング再生すると映像と音がずれる

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unity 2021.3.16f1を使っており、プラットフォームはWebGLです。
サーバーに配置したmp4をVideoPlayerで再生しようとしているのですが、タイトルの通り音声と映像がずれてしまいます。
具体的には、映像がフリーズしている間音声は止まらず音声だけが先行しています。
VideoPlayer.timeやVideoPlayer.frameは映像がフリーズしていても、音声と一緒にインクリメントされているのでバッファリング中を検知することもできません。
上記の現象は今のところWebGLのみで発現しています。
VideoPlayerの設定は以下の通りです。

```
　　　　 private VideoPlayer CreateVideoPlayer()
        {
            videoPlayerObject = new GameObject("VideoPlayerObject");
            videoPlayerObject.transform.parent = this.transform;
            videoPlayerObject.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
            var vp = videoPlayerObject.AddComponent<VideoPlayer>();
            VideoPlayerSetting(vp);
            return vp;
        }
 
        private void VideoPlayerSetting(VideoPlayer vp)
        {
            vp.prepareCompleted += OnPrepareCompleted;
            vp.renderMode = VideoRenderMode.MaterialOverride;
            vp.targetMaterialRenderer = screenRenderer;
            vp.playOnAwake = true;
            vp.isLooping = false;
            vp.waitForFirstFrame = true;
            vp.skipOnDrop = false;
            vp.source = VideoSource.Url;
            vp.audioOutputMode = VideoAudioOutputMode.Direct;
        }
```

こちらが生成されたVideoPlayerです。
[image: 生成されたVideoPlayer]

Unityフォーラムにも同じような内容投稿があり、回答でバージョンが古いといわれていますが本バージョンがLTSの最新なのでこれ以上はアップデートできません。
https://forum.unity.com/threads/audio-video-stuttering-on-webgl.1409379/

こちら何か対策はあるでしょうか？

Comment: プログラムの断片だけ提示されても、ピンポイントで問題・対処を把握している人以外は回答出来無さそうです。それよりは簡単に試せて問題を再現できるプロジェクト一式とテスト手順を用意して追記するか、量が多いのならそれへの紹介リンクを提示したほうが助言・回答が付きやすいと思われます。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) そうしたものを作る過程で自分自身で原因発見・解決出来ることがあるかもしれません。

Comment: ちなみに参照先の回答には版数の更新に続けて`2. Check the profiler if there are any performance concerns`とありますが、そちらはやってみたのでしょうか？

Comment: コメント・質問時のアドバイスありがとうございます。
情報不足で申し訳ありません。
本件はUnity（VideoPlayer）のバグというところまでは確定なので、ピンポイントで問題・対処を把握している方でないとそもそも回答できないと思っており設定部分しか提示しませんでした。
また、初めての質問ということもありヘルプ記事はとても助かりました！

パフォーマンスチェックはメモリ的には問題は無かったのですが、再生しようとした動画の中に解像度とBit rateが異様に高いものがあり、これらを最低限下げることにより多少改善されました。
ただ、根本的な原因ではないような気がするので、問題を回避できる抜け道を知っている方がいれば教えていただけると幸いです。